# Erro de conversão de tipo com EntityFramework: Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[]'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, entity-framework-6

Estou recebendo esse erro ao tentar gravar um novo registro de `Atendimento`.

> Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[Domain.AtendimentoAnexo]' no tipo 'Domain.AtendimentoAnexo'.

Classes:

**Atendimento**:

```cs
public class Atendimento
{
    public Atendimento()
    {
        Historicos = new HashSet<AtendimentoHistorico>();
        Anexos = new HashSet<AtendimentoAnexo>();
        Variaveis = new HashSet<Variavel>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Revenda")]
    public int RevendaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Revenda Revenda { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RevendaId, EmpresaId")]
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ClienteId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RevendaId, EmpresaId, ClienteId")]
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Departamento")]
    public int DepartamentoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Departamento Departamento { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AssuntoId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartamentoId, AssuntoId")]
    public virtual Assunto Assunto { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("SituacaoAtendimento")]
    public int SituacaoId { get; set; }
    public TipoSituacaoAtendimento SituacaoAtendimento { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150)]
    [ForeignKey("UsuarioCriador")]
    public string UsuarioCriadorLogin { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario UsuarioCriador { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150)]
    [ForeignKey("UsuarioSolicitante")]
    public string UsuarioSolicitanteLogin { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario UsuarioSolicitante { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150)]
    [ForeignKey("UsuarioResponsavel")]
    public string UsuarioResponsavelLogin { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario UsuarioResponsavel { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Solucao { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DataHoraSolicitacao { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DataHoraPrevistaEncerramento { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataHoraEncerramento { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string MeioAcesso { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Atendimento")]
    public virtual ICollection<AtendimentoHistorico> Historicos { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Atendimento")]
    public virtual ICollection<AtendimentoAnexo> Anexos { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Atendimento")]
    public virtual ICollection<Variavel> Variaveis { get; set; }
}
```

**AtendimentoAnexo**:

```cs
public class AtendimentoAnexo
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Revenda")]
    public int RevendaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Revenda Revenda { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RevendaId, EmpresaId")]
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int AtendimentoId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RevendaId, EmpresaId, AtendimentoId")]
    public virtual Atendimento Atendimento { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string UrlArquivo { get; set; }
}
```

Trecho para insert do registro:

```cs
var atendimento = new Domain.Atendimento();

using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        #region carrega atendimento ...

        atendimento.RevendaId = UsuarioLogado.RevendaId;
        atendimento.EmpresaId = UsuarioLogado.EmpresaId ?? 0;

        if (txtId.Text.IsPopulated())
            atendimento.Id = Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text.Replace(".", ""));

        if (txtDataSolicitacao.Text.IsPopulated() && txtHoraSolicitacao.Text.IsPopulated())
            atendimento.DataHoraSolicitacao = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDataSolicitacao.Text +
                " " + txtHoraSolicitacao.Text + ":00");

        if (ddlCliente.SelectedValue.IsPopulated())
            atendimento.ClienteId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCliente.SelectedValue);

        if (ddlDepatamento.SelectedValue.IsPopulated())
            atendimento.DepartamentoId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDepatamento.SelectedValue);

        if (ddlAssunto.SelectedValue.IsPopulated())
            atendimento.AssuntoId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlAssunto.SelectedValue);

        if (ddlSolicitante.SelectedValue.IsPopulated())
            atendimento.UsuarioSolicitanteLogin = ddlSolicitante.SelectedValue;

        atendimento.UsuarioCriadorLogin = UsuarioLogado.Login;

        if (UsuarioLogado.GrupoAcesso != Domain.GrupoAcesso.Cliente)
            atendimento.UsuarioResponsavelLogin = atendimento.UsuarioCriadorLogin;

        if (ddlMeioAcesso.SelectedValue.IsPopulated())
            atendimento.MeioAcesso = ddlMeioAcesso.SelectedValue;

        if (ddlSituacao.SelectedValue.IsPopulated())
            atendimento.SituacaoId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlSituacao.SelectedValue);

        var status = _context.TiposSituacaoAtendimento
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == atendimento.SituacaoId);
        if (status != null && status.Status == "2")
        {
            atendimento.DataHoraEncerramento = DateTime.Now;
            atendimento.Solucao = txtDescricao.Text;
        }

        atendimento.Descricao = txtDescricao.Text;

        #endregion carrega atendimento ...

        _context.Atendimentos.Add(atendimento); // O erro acontece aqui
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

Detalhe que nesse momento ainda não cheguei a alimentar a propriedade `Anexos` da classe `Atendimento`.

Antes as propriedades do tipo lista estavam declaradas como `List<T>` e dando o mesmo tipo de erro. Então passei para `ICollection<T>` para testar, pois é o tipo usado mais frequentemente.

O que pode estar causando esse problema?

---

### Como a mensagem de erro mostra, é claro que o EntityFramework está tratando minha propriedade como não sendo do tipo lista.

[image: EntityFramework Avacalhando]

E com isso a condição joga o fluxo para `TakeSnapshotOfSingleRelationship`.

```cs
var navigationProperties =
    (metadata.CdmMetadata.EdmType as EntityType).NavigationProperties;

foreach (var n in navigationProperties)
{
    var relatedEnd = rm.GetRelatedEndInternal(n.RelationshipType.FullName, n.ToEndMember.Name);
    var val = WrappedEntity.GetNavigationPropertyValue(relatedEnd);

    if (val != null)
    {
        if (n.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            // Reference
            TakeSnapshotOfSingleRelationship(relatedEnd, n, val);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: só uma obs: HashSet é mais lento eim.. rsrss

Comment: @Rod, essa eu não sabia.. Oo porque?

Comment: Quando você faz um **database-first** ou **model-first**, ou um reverso com **EntityFramework Power Tools**, o VS gera com esse tipo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance

Comment: @Rod, Esse gráfico me confundiu.. ao olhar diretamente para ele apenas, eu entendo que conforme cresce o tamanho de registros e objetos, `List<T>` tende a demorar muito mais.

Comment: Também vi isso @TiagoSilva, e é o que o autor escreveu tb, que o List é mais rápido até 20 objetos

Comment: @Caputo, grato! Agora entendi! =D

Comment: Porém.. e no EntityFramework, internamente, será que vale a pena ficar pensando em, onde colocar `[List<T>](null)` e onde colocar `HashSet<T>`? Isso não muda a forma como o EntityFramework trabalha? **;]**

Answer (score 2):

Identificando que o ***EntityFramework*** estava tratando minha propriedade como relacionamento simples (***Zero ou Um***, como mostra a imagem) e então gerando o erro, mudei minha abordagem para a de muito já discutido nas questões sobre ***EntityFramework***.

```cs
public class AtendimentoAnexo
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index("unq_AtendimentoAnexo", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("Revenda")]
    public int RevendaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Revenda Revenda { get; set; }

    [Index("unq_AtendimentoAnexo", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RevendaId, EmpresaId")]
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }

    [Index("unq_AtendimentoAnexo", IsUnique = true, Order = 3)]
    public int AtendimentoId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RevendaId, EmpresaId, AtendimentoId")]
    public virtual Atendimento Atendimento { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string UrlArquivo { get; set; }
}
```

E com isso o problema foi resolvido.

O erro estava em ter apenas esses campos como chave primária:

```cs
[Key]
[Column(Order = 0)]
[ForeignKey("Revenda")]
public int RevendaId { get; set; }
public virtual Revenda Revenda { get; set; }

[Key]
[Column(Order = 1)]
public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("RevendaId, EmpresaId")]
public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }

[Key]
[Column(Order = 2)]
public int AtendimentoId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("RevendaId, EmpresaId, AtendimentoId")]
public virtual Atendimento Atendimento { get; set; }
```

Sem um diferenciador, como faria para ter mais de um registro do mesmo atendimento? Um campo extra na chave resolveria também.